How do I define my type based on class so I can use that type in typecase and related expressions?
Consider this:
(defclass my-string ()
  ((data :initarg :data :type simple-string)
   (properties :initarg :properties :type interval-tree))
  (:documentation
   "Represents a string with properties."))

I would like to use my-string as a type in a typecase expression:
(defun upcase (obj)
  (typecase obj
    (my-string (string-upcase (slot-value obj 'data)))
    (string (string-upcase obj))
    (integer (char-upcase (code-char obj)))
    (character (char-upcase obj))
    (otherwise (error "Wrong type argument ~S" obj))))

I thought that classes are types, but obviously not, since the above is a compiler error. So I declared a type:
(deftype my-string (s) (typep s 'my-string))

which it seems I have to use like this (otherwise I get compilation error that typedef expects an argument):
(defun upcase (obj)
  (typecase obj
    ((my-string obj) (string-upcase (slot-value obj 'data)))
    (string (string-upcase obj))
    (integer (char-upcase (code-char obj)))
    (character (char-upcase obj))
    (otherwise (error "Wrong type argument ~S" obj))))

However SBCL deletes my code as unreachable! :-)
How do I do this? How to properly declare a type for a class so I can use it in expressions where type declarations are usable?
I understand I can use struct instead of class, in which case the compiler generates code for the type, and the initial typecase "just works":
(defstruct my-string
  data properties)

Macroexpanding and looking at the generated code didn't really make more enlightened. I see this:
(SB-C:XDEFUN MY-STRING-P
     :PREDICATE
     NIL
     (SB-KERNEL::OBJECT)
   (TYPEP SB-KERNEL::OBJECT 'MY-STRING))

which does exactly what I did, but I don't think that function is in the play, or am I wrong? Either they somehow associate structs with types internally, or I have missed some relevant part of the generated code? I am not very familiar with all this, so it is very likely as well.
A related question: what is the proper way to model a custom class that extends a built-in type like string in CommonLisp? Is it a better way to do the composition, as done in my-string, or is it perhaps better to inherit from some built-in CL string class? Based on this SX question and answers, it seems to me that inheritance is not the best way to model types, which is probably for the better, since we don't like taxonomies as known from Java or old C++.
Finally, I wouldn't even need typecase in this case if I made upcase a generic method that specialize on those types, the entire problem goes away, which I am fully aware of. However, I would like to learn more about types and classes, and how to model something like the above in CL.
Sorry if it is a bit long, and too many questions baked into one, I am just learning this. It feels like every question I have and experimenting for an answer opens 10 more questions :).

"since the above is a compiler error" -> there is no compiler error -> the code works. CLOS class names are type names.

You are using deftype in a completely wrong way, so even though there is a better answer I'd like to focus on the part that was errorneous.
When you write (deftype u (s) (typep s 'u)), the first time you have no warning, and later you have an warning during compilation if you try again (with SBCL), because u in (typep s 'u) doesn't have the expected number of arguments, defined by (deftype u (s) ...). This can be explained once we understand what deftype does.
TYPEP
First, in order for the (typep ...) call to make sense, you would need to write something like (typep v '(u s)) where v is a value, and (u s) is a type, parameterized by argument s. For example, (integer -2 -2) is such a type, it is a subset of integer with inclusive bounds:
(loop for i from -5 to 5 collect (list i (typep i '(integer -2 2))))
=> ((-5 NIL) (-4 NIL) (-3 NIL)
    (-2 T) (-1 T) (0 T) (1 T) (2 T) 
    (3 NIL) (4 NIL) (5 NIL))

The values with a T are the one when typep succeeds.
Type specifiers
Notice that the type above, the second argument, is a symbolic term. It's a an expression in a mini-language of types. In this language you have standard atomic type specifiers, like string, class, number, and then you can compose them as compound type specifiers, like the standard ones (and ...), (or ...), etc.
Finally, you can define your own type specifiers using deftype, and then the defined type can be used as a second argument to typep.
Note also that this notion of typing is quite different from Hindley–Milner type systems that are popular in other functional programing languages: you cannot define recursive types (like lists of integers), the type (or (or a b) c) is equivalent to (or a b c), etc. This is just not the same approach, that's something to remember when dealing with types.
DEFTYPE
Typically deftype is useful in your program when you want to give names to types you will use a lot, and also maybe to do a bit of abstraction over types. For example, writing octet is shorter than always using (unsigned-byte 8), so here we can define the type as follows:
(deftype octet () '(unsigned-byte 8))

Another example is when you want to constrain the underlying type, for example here a square matrix necessarily has two dimensions with the same size; the type here is a type specifier so that you can talk about square matrices of floats or integers, etc.:
(deftype square-matrix (size type)
  `(array ,type (,size ,size)))

With the above definition, here is how you would check if an array is actually a square matrix of integers:
(typep #2A((1 1) (2 2)) '(square-matrix 2 integer))

In conclusion, square-matrix is a function producing a type specifier, and that's what deftype is about.
Your my-string functions returns a generalized boolean (the result of typep), and the argument you wanted to give was a value (is s of type my-string), whereas s in a deftype argument is supposed to be used to express a type parameter, because you may have different variations of my-string (e.g. an explicit size parameter for your strings).
DEFCLASS
Going back to your original problem, the following works in a fresh environment:
(defclass foo () ())

(defun bar (v)
  (typecase v
    (string "a string")
    (foo "a foo")))


"I hope this clarifies things a bit." <-- Yes it does, quite a lot indeed! I understand now  what I didn't understand about typedefs this morning. I still don't know why my original class without typedef wasn't accepted, but I have tried in clean instance of sbcl and it seem to work. Very good explanation, and great example with 2D array. Thank you.

Any CLOS class has a corresponding type.
CL-USER 3 > (defclass foo () (a b c))
#<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 801000157B>

CL-USER 4 > (type-of *)
STANDARD-CLASS

CL-USER 5 > (make-instance 'foo)
#<FOO 801000568B>

CL-USER 6 > (type-of *)
FOO

CL-USER 7 > (typep (make-instance 'foo) 'foo)
T

The class object of the class FOO has a type STANDARD-CLASS.
Instances of the class FOO are of type FOO.
Thus TYPECASE works with type names for CLOS classes:
CL-USER 8 > (dolist (object (list 1 "2" (make-instance 'foo)))
              (typecase object
                (number (format t "~% ~s is a number" object)) 
                (string (format t "~% ~s is a string" object)) 
                (foo    (format t "~% ~s is a CLOS object of class ~a"
                                object (class-of object)))))

 1 is a number
 "2" is a string
 #<FOO 8010000E2B> is a CLOS object of class #<STANDARD-CLASS FOO 81400243A3>


I think I had some garbage left in my image; as usually I had my laptop and SBCL process on for several days. After running in a clean instance, it worked. I have to get used to actually restart the lisp process after experimenting and testing. But thanks anyway.

Class-wise behavior you do best implement using the multiple dispatch capability of Common Lisp CLOS (in this case, only single dispatch is needed) - by using generic function macros defgeneric and defmethod.
The good thing of using dispatch is anyway that you are much more flexible and the class-wise selection is extensible later (much better for maintenance). Not only that - if you import this code (e.g. as a package) - the code which uses this code (this code embedded in a package) - can still extend the dispatching (add new cases / new classes for the dispatch) which is a very powerful feature in programming.
And in as much dispatch is superior to typecase. Although typecase is of course faster in speed.
(defclass my-string ()
  ((data :initarg :data :type simple-string)
   (properties :initarg :properties :type interval-tree))
  (:documentation
   "Represents a string with properties."))

You write first a generic function using defgeneric:
(defgeneric upcase (obj)
  (:documentation "A generic function to upcase different types of objects."))

Then you write using defmethod each auf the clauses as separate method functions:
;; the general form is:
;; (defmethod upcase ((obj the-type-or-class-of-obj))
;;    ... specific code handling `obj` ...)


(defmethod upcase ((obj my-string))
  (string-upcase (slot-value obj 'data)))

(defmethod upcase ((obj string))
  (string-upcase obj))

(defmethod upcase ((obj integer))
  (char-upcase (code-char obj)))

(defmethod upcase ((obj character))
  (char-upcase obj))

(defmethod upcase ((obj t))
  (error "Wrong type argument ~S" obj))

Try the code by:
(let ((custom-string (make-instance 'my-string :data "hello" :properties nil)))
  (format t "Upcased my-string: ~A~%" (upcase custom-string)))

(format t "Upcased plain string: ~A~%" (upcase "world"))

(format t "Upcased integer: ~A~%" (upcase 97))  ; ASCII code for 'a'

(format t "Upcased character: ~A~%" (upcase #\a))

(handler-case
    (upcase '(1 2 3))
  (error (e) (format t "Error: ~A~%" e)))

;; The output should be:
Upcased my-string: HELLO ; NIL
Upcased plain string: WORLD ; NIL
Upcased integer: A ; NIL
Upcased character: A ; NIL
Error: Wrong type argument (1 2 3) ; NIL


Thank you for taking the time to look at my question and for the kind answer. As stated at the very end of my question, I am very much aware of generic dispatch, and I am very much familiar with how to implement the above with generic methods, so that is why I didn't ask about how to do it with generic methods. While I appreciate your time and effort, that unfortunately does not answer what I ask about.

Oh I totally overlooked that sentence. I think such thing belongs to the beginning of such a question. Because you are differing from the canonical way of handling such problems in Common Lisp.

No worries, I understand you just wanted to share your knowledge. I also totally agree that the generic method is better in this case, but I sort of knew that before I asked the question, as well as how to code it. But perhaps someone else in the future will find it useful, so I don't want to downvote your or such.

@coredump answered correctly.
In some cases, instead of typecase a dispatching via predicates might be meaningful.
You could write a macro:
(defmacro predcase (obj &rest clauses)
  "A version of TYPECASE that uses predicates."
  `(cond
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (clause)
                 (let ((predicate (car clause))
                       (body (cdr clause)))
                   `((,predicate ,obj) ,@body)))
               clauses)))

And then use it like this:
(defun upcase (obj)
  (predcase obj
    (my-string-p
     (string-upcase (slot-value obj 'data)))
    (stringp
     (string-upcase obj))
    (integerp
     (char-upcase (code-char obj)))
    (characterp
     (char-upcase obj))
    (t
     (error "Wrong type argument ~S" obj))))

But I know this was not actually the question.

Sure, if custom predicates are interesting, but than we are more in the waters of a pattern matching, than switching on a type, and job for a library like Trivia.
